# fixed point of a continuous map on a projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $f:S^{2n} \rightarrow S^{2n}$ be a continuous map. Show that
>
> 1. there exists $x \in S^{2n}$, such that $f(x) =x$ or $f(x) = -x$;
> 2. any continous map $g: \mathbb R P^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb RP^{2n}$ has a fixed point;

I think 1 implies 2. So, how can I find an $x$ in 1?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What exactly is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: @KrisWilliams: Thanks for reminding me. I am trying to find the $x$ in 1.

Comment: Are you aware of the hairy ball theorem?

Comment: Please label homework problems as such.

Comment: As a general rule in topology, we can often show that such a point exists without showing a way to "find" such a point - we just show that if such a point did not exist, then we'd reach a contradiction.

Comment: @sunkist, how did you prove that 1 implies 2?

Comment: @Sigur Given $f:RP^{2n}\to RP^{2n}$ and the canonical surjection $p:S^{2n}\to RP^{2n}$, you can lift $fp$ to a map $g:S^{2n}\to S^{2n}$ (so that $pg=fp$) because $p$ is a universal cover of $RP^2$. Then $g(x)=\pm x$ for some $x$, so that $f(p(x))=p(g(x))=p(\pm x)=p(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $f(x)\neq -x$ for all $x$, show $f$ is homotopic to the identity, $I:S^{2n}\to S^{2n}$.  If $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x$, show $f$ is homotopic to $-I$. Therefore, if $f(x)\neq \pm x$ for all $x$, then $I$ and $-I$ are homotopic.

Presumably, you know that in $S^{2n}$ that $I$ and $-I$ cannot be homotopic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.