# Projective plane, fixed point

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

How to show, that for every continuous $f:  X\rightarrow X$ there exists $x \in X$, such that $f(x) = x$, where X is a real projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

In other words: every continuous map of RPP to itself has a fixed point.

EDIT

Probably it's easier to proof, that existence of fixed point in map from $S^2$ to itself implies needed fact.

Comment: @DietrichBurde in that question there are two statements, and author says that first implies second, and there is proof of the first one. But I'm not sure if I understand the implication.

Comment: This follows easily from the argument of "Anonymous". But anyway, there is no problem to find proofs here. Start searching. I found the [next one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590675/does-every-continuous-map-f-mathbbr-mathbbpn-to-mathbbr-mathbbp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406851/fixed-point-of-a-continuous-map-on-a-projective-space) reduces your question to the following implication, which you said you don't know how to do:

> (1) for any continuous map $f : S^{2n} \to S^{2n}$ there exists $x \in S^{2n}$, such that $f(x) =x$ or $f(x) = -x$;

implies

> (2) any continous map $g: \mathbb R P^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb RP^{2n}$ has a fixed point.

To prove this implication, given a continuous $g: \mathbb R P^k \rightarrow \mathbb RP^k$, define $f : S^k \to S^k$ as follows. First, let $p : S^k \to \mathbb R P^k$ be the universal covering map. By composition we obtain $g \circ p : S^k \to \mathbb R P^k$. Applying the general lifting lemma, we obtain a continuous map $f = \widetilde{g \circ p} : S^k \to S^k$ such that $p \circ f = g \circ p$. Applying (1), we obtain $x$ such that $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$, and it follows that 
$$g(p(x)) = p(f(x)) = p(\pm x) = p(x)
$$
and so $p(x)$ is the required fixed point of $g$.

Comment: But why $p(\pm x) = p(x)$?

Comment: Well, $p(x)=p(-x)$ for all $x$, almost by definition of $p$. Would it be clearer if I wrote this? $$p(f(x)) \in \{p(x),p(-x)\} = \{p(x)\}$$

Comment: Not really, I'm new in topology:(. I understand the geometry behind $p$, but I don't get this kind of symmetry. Could you explain, how it follows from the definition?

Comment: The definition of what? Do you know the definition of $S^k$? of $\mathbb R P^k$? of $p : S^k \to \mathbb R P^k$?

Comment: Yeah, I know them all. Still unclear, why  ()=(−) for all , almost by definition of  . Then probably I don't understand definition of $S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: What definition of $\mathbb R P^2$ do you understand?

Comment: I'll just add, the first definition of $\mathbb R P^2$ that students learn can vary highly, depending on what kind of course they first see it in. So the definition of $p$ therefore also varies highly.

Comment: It's from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Classical_examples

Comment: Then, using the language of that link: any pair of antipodal points $x,-x \in S^2$ lie on a unique a line $L$ in $\mathbb R^3$; that line $L$ passes through the origin of $\mathbb R^3$ and is therefore a 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$; that line $L$ therefore represents a unique point in $\mathbb R P^2$; and the projection map $p : S^2 \to \mathbb RP^2$, by definition, takes each of the two points $x,-x$ to the point of $\mathbb R P^2$ represented by the line $L$.

Comment: Finally got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of help.